# Slim framework get the data from a form

Tags: php, forms, slim

I try to make a simple form with SLIM framework.
I don't know how to display the posted data. I want just to try to echo it.
I heard that I need to use extra library RESPECT, I think SLIM can do such small thing.

here is my code :

```
require '../../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
    $app->render('form.php');
});

$app->post('/', function() use ($app){
    $req = $app->request();
    $errors = array();
    $params = array(
        'email' => array(
            'name'=>'Email',
            'required'=>true,
            'max_length'=>64,
        ),
        'subject' => array(
            'name'=>'Subject',
            'required'=>true,
            'max_length'=>256,
        ),
      );
        //submit_to_db($email, $subject, $message);
        $app->flash('message','Form submitted!');

    $app->redirect('./');
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Slim 2, you can access to your posted data using `post()` method of `request()`:

```
$app->post('/', function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app->request();
    $email = $request->post('Email');
    $subject = $request->post('Subject');
    echo "Email: $email<br/>";
    echo "Subject: $subject";
});
```

In Slim 3, the request is passed to the callback/controller/etc. and you can call `getParam()` which fetches the value from body or query string (in that order):

```
$app->post('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $email = $request->getParam('Email');
    $subject = $request->getParam('Subject');
    echo "Email: $email<br/>";
    echo "Subject: $subject";
});
```

Starting from [Slim 3.1](https://www.slimframework.com/2016/01/08/slim-3.1.0.html) there are also `getParsedBodyParam()` and `getFetchParam()` which fetch only from body or query string. ([PR #1620](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/pull/1620))

Just as a reminder, you can provide a default value: `$request->getParam('Email', 'default_value')`

Comment: @bourax How do you send your data? A normal HTML form or an Ajax request?

Comment: It works now, thank you. the problem was in  $app->redirect('./');  now I use  $app->flash('email',$email);
$app->flash('subject',$subject);  then echo them in the form.php  echo $flash['subject'];  I used your way to save in the DB, thank you